# How to troubleshoot OpenSSL BN_bin2bn() causing segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, openssl, segmentation-fault, elliptic-curve

Calling the following method produces a segmentation fault on the `BN_bin2bn` call:

```
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#define ECIES_PUBLIC_KEY_SIZE 32

static int doBin2Bn(const uint8_t* someValue)
{
    BIGNUM *bn = NULL;
    bn = BN_new();
    BN_bin2bn(someValue, ECIES_PUBLIC_KEY_SIZE, bn);
}
```

The value of `someValue` in `%02x` format is `33313338`.

Why would this cause a seg fault?

Comment: The buffer pointed to by someValue must not be 32 bytes long. Post how you are calling the function; without seeing how you coming up with someValue it's hard to offer much help.

Comment: *"How to troubleshoot OpenSSL BN_bin2bn()..."* - Compile OpenSSL and your program at `-O1`, and then use Valgrind. Valgrind requests `-O1`; see [The Valgrind Quick Start Guide](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.prepare).